# $A(Bv)=B(Av)=B(\lambda v)=\lambda Bv$, $\lambda$ the eigenvalue of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $A,B$ be linear maps of $V$ into itself. Assume that $AB=BA$. Show that if  $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$ also if $Bv\neq 0$.

SOLUTION. We have

$A(Bv)=B(Av)=B(\lambda v)=\lambda Bv$.***Solutions Manual for Lang´s Linear Algebra,Rami Shakarchi.***

**Question**:

Given $B(\lambda v)=\lambda Bv$? How do I know $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $B$? If I take $5x6=x5\times 6$ however $x=1$.

Comment: $\lambda$ needs not to be the eigenvalue of $B$. The reason we have $B(\lambda v) = \lambda B(v)$ is because $B$ is a linear map.

Comment: @jing007               The solution is intended to prove that $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **v** is an eigenvector of **A** then $$A v = \lambda v$$
Multiply by **B** on the left:
$$B(Av)=B(\lambda v)$$
$$(BA)v=\lambda (Bv)$$
$$(AB)v=\lambda (Bv)$$
$$A(Bv)=\lambda (Bv)$$
This last expression shows that $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if it is not the null vector by definition.

Answer (score 0):

$B(\lambda v)=\lambda (Bv)$ because $\lambda$ is a scalar, and can be freely moved around matrices like $B$ and $v$.  See the third property [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties_of_the_matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29).

$\lambda$ need not be an eigenvalue of $B$.

Comment: The solution is trying to prove that $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $B$. It is assumed that $AB=BA$.